# Formulating a negatively-expressed question

Tags: questions, negation

I'm a non-native speaker completely stuck trying to formulate a negative question. Full disclosure: I'd like to use it as a title for a university paper and I could not find any help around.

This is the question/title:

> Why **did** the Industrial Revolution **did not** occur in China during the Ming/Qing period?

I highlighted the sources of my doubts.

In the title I'd like to ask why the Industrial Revolution (which happened in Britain) *did not happen* (during the same period) in China.

Should I rather say

> Why **did** the Industrial Revolution **not** occur in China during the Ming/Qing period?

Thank you in advance

Edit: maybe this question should belong to "english language learners"

Comment: You should rather say what you "should rather say"

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is correct.

When negating questions, we use the construction *auxiliary verb + subject + negation + verb*, which in your example translates to "*did + the Industrial Revolution + not + occur*".

There's some more information here: http://www.englishgrammar.org/negative-questions/